# Jersey client: how to access an HTTPS service

Tags: java, https, jersey

I have been googling a lot for this problem. There are many relevant answers, but I simply didn't find one that gave a complete view IMHO. So, here I am.

The statement of problem is as follows. Given the API information of an HTTPS service, including URL and any required HTTP headers and body format, how do you use a Jersey client to access the service? Note that the statement doesn't assume the client side has any other information from the target service beforehand.

As we know, when a web browser tries to access an HTTPS site, behind the scene, the browser will first get a certificate and a public key from the site. Then, if the browser trusts the certificate, it will use the public key to encrypt the actual request and send it. I have found many examples that explain how to use Jersey client for HTTPS given a truststore that incorporates the certificate and the public key. However, what if the truststore is not available yet? Can we use Jersey client, programmatically, to get the site certificate and public key, and use them to send the actual request, as a web browser does?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Are you talking about a Jersey client that does two-way authentication or simply a client that accesses an SSL encrypted web service? If it's the latter, as long as your client machine is using the default trust store, it should just work. This works because the default trust store automatically trusts the root certificate authorities. Of course, if you're using a self-signed certificate on your server, you'll have to do something else.